# How do I add a field in the toolbar?

Tags: 8

How do I add a custom field in the toolbar?

[image: Is it possible?]

Answer (score 0):

The examples module kinda does this:

[image]

it's not a drop down, but lists the links under. Take a look at `// Create the examples toolbar render array.` in [examples.module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/examples.module) to see how they do it.

---

**Now, I don't know if you can put an actual field in the toolbar with PHP code**. The only thing that I can think of is to use CSS. I tested this and it worked.

`.field-in-question { position: fixed; top: 10px; z-index: 999; }`